# golang udp client can't receive msg from server

Tags: go

i can send msg from client to server successfully. But when i try to reply message back to client, somehow client cant receive the message.

Client:

```
conn, _:= net.Dial("udp", serv_addr:port)
defer conn.close()
buf:= []byte("Hey, server")
conn.Write(buf)

recv:= make([]byte, 1024)
fmt.Println("Reading...\n")
conn.Read(recv)
```

Server:

```
addr, _:= net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", addr:port)
msg := make([]byte, 1024)

conn,_: net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
_, ret_addr, _: conn.ReadFromUDP(msg)
//print msg
conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("got your msg", ret)
```

It's a very simple udp connection. server can printout the msg from client, but on client side, it keeps waiting before conn.read() while server finished its task.

I followed [this](http://www.minaandrawos.com/2016/05/14/udp-vs-tcp-in-golang/) article. my implementation is almost identical.

Comment: start logging errors, u may find smth useful

Comment: Show the actual code you use, because this can't compile. You can't use an `io.Reader` properly while discarding errors and the bytes read value. You almost never want to use a use connected udp socket for the client. Your linked blog post is pretty poor quality, I would find better sources if you're not sure how networking works.

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804927/1099314. Have no fun!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimum code for you to play around with.

start a server part in one terminal:

`go run main.go server :53033`

start client in the other terminal:

`go run main.go client :53033`

now type messages at the **client** terminal and you should see both client and server exchanging messages. You can start multiple clients (in new terminal windows) and communicate with the same server.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func server(url string) {
    log.Printf("serving on %s\n", url)
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", url)
    errcheck(err)

    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
    errcheck(err)
    defer close(conn)

    msg := make([]byte, 1024)

    for {
        n, retAddr, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(msg)
        errcheck(err)

        log.Printf("received %v bytes, ret addr %v, msg %s", n, retAddr, string(msg[:n]))

        reply := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("received from you: %v bytes", n))
        n, err = conn.WriteToUDP(reply, retAddr)
        errcheck(err)

        log.Printf("sent reply %v bytes\n", n)
    }
}

func client(url string) {
    log.Printf("client for server url: %s\n", url)

    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", url)
    errcheck(err)

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, addr)
    errcheck(err)
    defer close(conn)

    msg := make([]byte, 512)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        if scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()

            n, err := conn.Write([]byte(line))
            errcheck(err)
            log.Printf("sent %d bytes \n", n)

            n, err = conn.Read(msg)
            errcheck(err)
            log.Printf("server replied with: %s \n", string(msg[:n]))
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]

    if len(args) < 2 {
        log.Fatal("expecting 2 arguments client or server first followed by the address:port")
    }

    switch args[0] {
    case "server":
        server(args[1])

    case "client":
        client(args[1])

    default:
        log.Fatal("first argument must be server or client")
    }

}

func errcheck(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func close(c io.Closer) {
    err := c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal()
    }
}
```

Have fun!